# Run Remote Linux Script as if I am at remote machine

Tags: linux

I am able to run remote script in two ways.
First (indirect)
 #ssh  
Second (after ssh connection)
 #ssh 
 #
 #exit (back to host terminal)

I believe that there is some difference in type of channel forwarding.
In other words when I used fist way fo running remote script, output of script should be printed not host mashine but remote one like that of the second way.

I have two machines uturksat1 and uturksat2
In uturksat2, I have a linux script (/tmp/runScript.sh) and Java class Provider. Linux script runs the Provider java application which is open a socket then listening it.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Provider"
$JAVA_HOME/bin/java -cp /tmp  Provider&
$JAVA_HOME/bin/java -version
rm  /tmp/pid
echo "$!"> /tmp/pid
echo "Provider-finish"
exit 0
```

On uturksat1 machine, I have type following command

```
root@UTURKSAT1:/tmp# ssh  uturksat2 /tmp/runScript.sh
Provider
java version "1.6.0_29"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_29-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 20.4-b02, mixed mode, sharing)
Provider-finish
Waiting for connection
```

It does not return command prompt automatically, I have to press ctrl+c to return

When I have type the following command:

```
root@UTURKSAT1:/tmp# ssh -t  uturksat2 /tmp/runScript.sh
Provider
Waiting for connection
java version "1.6.0_29"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_29-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 20.4-b02, mixed mode, sharing)
Provider-finish
Connection to uturksat2 closed.
root@UTURKSAT1:/tmp#
```

Provider app is not run, I can test it through telnet to port 2004 which Provider is listening.

```
telnet  uturksat2 2004
```

Finally last problem is that Provider uses log4j to keep its internall log, in the first way of remote linux script execution, log4j lof file is not created, but in the second way it is created.

Comment: Please explain exactly the commands you tried, and the output you've got, and the wanted output. `ssh remotehost prog arg` is running on `remotehost` the ̀`prog` with `arg` but redirect the remote stdout & stderr locally. Read http://support.suso.com/supki/SSH_Tutorial_for_Linux or some other documentation about `ssh` ; you may want to run `ssh -v` ... to understand what is happenning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have openned same question with different explanation. It has been solved. Thanks your advices which keep my motivation high. Here is the solution as you have already known.
[Run remote java server in linux script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12767905/run-remote-java-server-in-linux-script)

Answer (score 2):

The only difference between these two commands:

```
ssh second
script
exit
```

and

```
ssh second script
```

is that in the second case, the script will be started without terminal. To force terminal in the second case you must specify `-t`:

```
ssh -t second script
```

**Update.1**

If you want to start the `script` in the background and leave `ssh` session:

```
ssh second 'nohup script < /dev/null > nohup.out 2>&1 &'
```

Comment: I have tested it but it does not work. I have updated my question giving detailed explanation.

Comment: All works as it should. Which result do you want to get at the end?

Comment: It is as I explained. It does not what I want. I want to run an application intalled on remote host without any difference than that I connected remote machine manually.

Comment: ssh  uturksat2 'nohup /tmp/runScript.sh&'
It keeps waiting as well. Do not return console automatically.

Comment: Actually I do not want to send the linux process bakground by adding &. I want to track the execution steps then what to know the success state of execution. It has be be like that since I have an other java programm that call the "ssh host script" than waitfor the result.