# Run remote java server in linux script

Tags: java, linux, ssh

I have a Server implemented in Java named Provider, and linux script to start it.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Provider"
$JAVA_HOME/bin/java -cp /tmp  Provider&
$JAVA_HOME/bin/java -version
rm  /tmp/pid
echo "$!"> /tmp/pid
echo "Provider-finish"
exit 0
```

When I want to execute the following script at different machine (machine2)

```
root@machine1:/tmp# ssh  machine2/tmp/runScript.sh
Provider
java version "1.6.0_29"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_29-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 20.4-b02, mixed mode, sharing)
Provider-finish
Waiting for connection
```

The problem is that after running above script, it does not return console, it hang-up though Provider gets started.

I have analized similar concepts like Glassfish domain starting. by executing

```
ssh machine2 asadmin start-domain
```

it returns console without any problem so I can get execution status "$?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the problem is that the remote `sshd` won't close the ssh session because there is still a java process running in the background that *might* try to write output.

Try redirecting the background processes stdout and stderr to "/dev/null"; e.g.

```
$JAVA_HOME/bin/java -cp /tmp Provider > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

Comment: You are right, since java process tries to write outout sshd does not close ssh session. It is somehow understood when running same script locally. I have forwarded java process output to /dev/null as you suggested problem has been solved. Thanks.